# Setting a user written function as a label function

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, scripting

Is it possible to set a function written by the user (meaning that the whole function is written in a string variable) as the label function for a datagrid, or to generally just set it as a parameter for a function which accepts a function reference.
Maybe in such a way that the declaration is hardcoded, but the content being user written.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like scripting, so maybe this project fulfills your needs:

http://code.google.com/p/as3scriptinglib/

Excerpt from the [BasicFlexExample](http://code.google.com/p/as3scriptinglib/wiki/BasicFlexExample):

```
private function compilerInit(event:CompilerEvent):void
{
    compiler.compileAndLoad("trace('Hello, World!');");
}
```

Comment: Well, we already use scripting, for instance, a user may write code for several event (onClick, CreationComplete...), but i dont think that it isnt very applicable here.

Comment: @M364M4Ncro so then explain what is for your the difference between a "whole function is written in a string variable" and scripting?

Comment: well, now that i think about it some more, it could work, i will have to look into it